# YouTube link that automatically plays full screen in mobile safari

Tags: ios, html, video, youtube

I am trying to replicate the functionality of YouTube embedded videos on iOS without actually embedding the video.

When a user clicks an embedded YouTube video in Safari on an iPhone it will immediately start playing the video full screen in safari (not the YouTube app). Is there any way to get this same functionality from a regular link and not the full video embed?

I have succeeded in getting a video link to open in the YouTube app and also to open in youtube.com's mobile site, but I can't get it to just play in Safari without actually embedding the video.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you could use js to replace the link with the embedded version and set it to play automatically.

change the innerHTML to the embed:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/x1EgSwmps6Q?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Notice that the iframe src sets autoplay to 1 so it autoplays

the part between embed/ and ?auto is the same as v= in normal youtube URLs (ie https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1EgSwmps6Q )

Comment: autoplay is disabled on iOS so it will be ignored whether you include it in the url or not. I already basically have it working the way you suggest. What I'd like to do is cut out the extra step. So right now the flow is click link -> embedded video is displayed -> click video -> watch video full screen on iPhone. I'd like to change this to click link -> watch video full screen on iPhone. Apparently Apple even prevents the hacky work around of using js to automatically click on the embed once it loads. They don't want autoplay wasting mobile bandwidth.